# ¿Qué damos cuando "damos largas"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, significado

En España (al menos) la expresión coloquial [dar largas](https://dle.rae.es/largo#MwNMwao) significa

> 18. f. Dilación, retardación.

Viendo las acepciones de largo/a vemos que como adjetivo puede significar tanto "dilatado" o "extenso" como "pronto" o "expedito"

> 5. adj. Dilatado, extenso, continuado. *Un cirujano de larga experiencia.*
> 6. adj. Pronto, expedito, que hace algo en abundancia. *Este oficial es largo en trabajar.*

Sobre un periodo de tiempo significa "(subjetivamente) prolongado"

> 7. adj. Dicho de un período de tiempo: Subjetivamente prolongado. U. m. en pl. *Estuvo ausente largos años.*

Pero cuando consideramos las expresiones "Dar largas; Traer en largas", ¿a qué hacen referencias esas *largas* exactamente?

No pueden ser "periodos de tiempo", ya que entonces diríamos "largas". ¿Es "largas excusas"? ¿"Largas dilataciones" en responder?

¿Puede alguien arrojar algo de luz sobre el origen de la expresión o clarificar de otra manera qué son esas "largas"?

Comment: También en Argentina se usa esta expresión, pero generalmente se dice "Darle largas al asunto".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No tengo claro que el origen de la expresión tenga algo que ver con la tauromaquia, como se indica en otras respuestas. Sí que es cierto que el diccionario incluye la siguiente acepción en el artículo *[largo](https://dle.rae.es/largo)*:

> 19. f. *Taurom*. Lance a una mano que consiste en sacar al toro de la suerte de varas, corriéndolo con el capote extendido a lo largo.

Sin embargo, también incluye esta otra, apuntada en la pregunta:

> 18. f. Dilación, retardación. *Dar largas. Traer en largas.*

Esta definición de *larga* aparece en diccionarios antiguos, por ejemplo en el *Autoridades* (tomo A, 1734):

> LARGA. s.f. Dilacion, tardanza y entretenimiento de tiempo. Usase frequentemente en plurál.

Y cita el siguiente ejemplo:

> *Cansado pues de tantas largas el Sumo Sacerdote, determinó de preguntarle claramente lo que él deseaba oir de su boca.*

Incluso se puede encontrar en un diccionario español-inglés de 1604:

> Largas, *Delay*.

Esto ya es más antiguo que los primeros textos que encuentro en la hemeroteca que hablan de *lances* en el toreo, que son del siglo XVIII.

Ejemplos como el de arriba se encuentran en la literatura desde el siglo XVI al menos:

> *Pues como en Vitoria rreclamase el pueblo para que no obiese tantas largas en yr a castigar esta rebelion y muertes, los alcaldes, y avn creo quel cabildo, nonbraron por caudillo e juez para ello a Lorenço Rufas [...].*
>
> Fray Pedro de Aguado, "Historia de Santa Marta y Nuevo Reino de Granada", c 1573 - 1581 (Colombia).

E incluso descubro en un texto del siglo XIV la palabra en una especie de catálogo de expresiones:

> *Muchas: Excusas, largas (p.e. "dar muchas").*
>
> Anónimo, "Fuero viejo de Castilla", 1356 (España).

Este catálogo de expresiones se usan a lo largo del citado libro, por ejemplo:

> *E si otro ome fuer a desafiar, que non sea Fijodalgo, e le dieren muchas, tenerselas a con derecho.*

Se sabe pues que en el siglo XIV en Castilla se podía decir "dar largas" o "dar muchas". Esto ya indica, según mi opinión, que la expresión no tiene nada que ver con el lance del toreo. En el siglo XIII se podía usar *largas* con el significado de *muchas*:

> *E por auentura acaéceles que fuyen porque las echan largas uezes e las fazen mucho caçar.*
>
> Abraham de Toledo, "Moamín. Libro de los animales que cazan", 1250 (España).

Mi opinión es que en un origen la expresión podría haber sido "dar largas excusas", con el significado de dar muchas excusas, y que al final la expresión se quedó en "dar largas" (o "dar muchas", como hemos visto), adquiriendo la palabra *largas* significado propio, pudiéndose usar incluso suelta o con otros verbos.

Comment: Voy a aceptar esta respuesta porque, con la información que tenemos de momento, a mi también me cuadra más que "largas" en algún momento significase "dilación, retraso" o se usase como "largas excusas o dilaciones". No me gustan los toros y no conozco la jerga (aunque por aquí han pasado ya algunas preguntas), pero estoy seguro de que ese "lance largo" o larga es una entre muchas cosas que se pueden hacer para apartar al toro, y sin mayor evidencia que la casualidad o similitud, prefiero no dar por buena esa teoría teniendo los datos que aporta esta respuesta.

Comment: Añado enlace:  [Pases del toreo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pases_del_toreo): viene "La Larga Cambiada o Larga Natural, se llaman **largas** aquellos lances que [...]" PArece ser que la invención de algunos de estos lances puede ser incluso "rastreada" a su inventor. Creo que aparte de las "largas" hay gran cantidad de otros quites, pases o movimientos que vienen a conseguir algo parecido. Vamos, que si la expresión fuese "dar _quites_ al asunto" me creería un poco más que viene del toreo. Viendo esa cantidad de jerga, creo que la similitud es circunstancial y no causal.

Comment: También del enlace, por si lo quieres añadir: "**el lance más antiguo empleado en 1830**, descrito extensamente tanto en la Cartilla de torear como por Pepe-Hillo y por Paquiro en sus Tauromaquias ", lo que vendría a confirmar que las referencias aportadas son anteriores a la jerga del toreo.

Answer (score 2):

Si nos fiamos del [blog de 20minutos](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-dar-largas/amp/):

> El origen de la expresión ‘dar largas’ nada tiene que ver con las luces de largo alcance o carretera de un automóvil, sino que lo encontramos en los ambientes taurinos,  donde la ‘larga’ es un lance que hace el torero con el capote y con el que intenta engañar al toro, enviándolo hacia otro lado del ruedo.

Aunque no he encontrado fuentes más autoritarias, esta teoría se menciona en varias fuentes, y parece razonable. El significado "engañar al toro, enviándolo al otro lado del ruedo" encaja perfectamente con el sentido figurado que le doy a la expresión "dar largas" cuando la uso.

Comment: Parece tener sentido, sí. Solemos ser algo escépticos con las teorías de Alfred López, pues raramente aporta fuentes.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' de hecho yo suelo ser muy escéptico con las teorías de Alfred, y la investigación que puedes leer en mi respuesta creo que esta vez me da la razón (a menos que el mencionado lance del toreo sea más antiguo que el idioma).

Answer (score -1):

`Dar largas` significa poner escusas para alargar algo, o hacer algo dentro de mucho tiempo.

ejemplo: 'le pedí un móvil nuevo y me dio largas', quiere decir que no le va a comprar un móvil ahora y puede que no se lo compre, le puso escusas para no hacerlo ahora, y seguramente, escusa tras escusa para no hacerlo al final.

El origen es taurino, según https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-dar-largas/ Tiene que ver con un movimiento del capote para engañar al toro.

Comment: Mmmm había un comentario mío por aquí indicando que el significado ya lo conoce el autor de la pregunta. Dado que editaste, nótese que la referencia ya la dio wimi en su respuesta.

Comment: dado que lo has leído, nótese la escala temporal de las modificaciones, yo lo encontré primero

Comment: La respuesta de wimi se publicó antes y su primera versión ya contenía la referencia.